At what point should one start the exercise motion on machines
On some machines, for example the Pro 2 Biceps Curl, one is able to move the apparatus using the curl motion without the weight actually being lifted.  In my mind, this would build momentum before the weight is actually lifted.  Should one then not start the curl motion before the weights are lifted, but only slowly bring the apparatus to where the weight will now be lifted and then begin the motion?

There should not be any segment of the range of motion in which a weights machine releases the load while the movement is still being performed. If your machine is doing this, I would suspect that it is not properly calibrated, such that the cables need shortening to ensure that the weights come to rest on the plate stack at the bottom of the machine's possible range of motion.

That or they're positioned incorrectly in the machine; for the bicep curl the seat should be low enough that you'd need to stand up to grab the handles, thus creating tension at the bottom of the movement. Of course one could stand up and jerk the handles back while seating to create momentum...

It's not that the machine "releases the load," it's that one is able to perform the beginning of the exercise motion without the weights being moved.  So that if one wanted to he could build a lot of momentum before actually being resisted by the weights, which would make the lift easier.

Yes, that is what I mean by the machine releasing the load. There is a segment of the motion where the weights are not moving. That shouldn't happen.

@DavidScarlett so should one only start the explosive curl motion at the point at which he is being resisted, and not before then?  i tried doing this and it's a lot harder to do, probably because you don't have that momentum from moving the handles without being resisted.  it also feels unnatural because you're starting the explosive curl movement at a point in the curl movement that it's not meant for.  usually it's meant to do at the beginning of the motion, I believe.

@tomorwoh38hx it's pretty unusual to be performing an explosive movement on a machine. Why are you doing that, rather than lifting in a controlled manner?

@DavidScarlett the point is I can only do an explosive movement on the biceps curl machine in question if I start where one should, because there's no resistance at that point.  but now i can't do an explosive movement because I'm starting the movement at the point in the curl that one is not supposed to start the movement, in order to only start the "explosive" movement at a point where I am being resisted by the weights.  but i say explosive only in the sense of maximum effort, because it's a very slow motion, as I explained, because I am starting the explosion basically in the middle

@tomorwoh38hx you should really get the machine fixed so that it provides resistance across the entire range of motion. It's rather suboptimal if it provides no resistance during the longer muscle length parts of the range of motion.

@DavidScarlett are you saying the beginning of the motion involves longer muscle lengths than the middle or end, and if so, is that why it's so much harder to complete the rep when you start in the middle of the motion?

In a bicep curl, the biceps are longest when the arm is straight. This part of the exercise is also the most beneficial for hypertrophy. But this is not the reason why you find it more difficult starting in the middle of the motion. That's more that you're using the no-resistance portion of the range of motion to build momentum that gets you through the rest of the movement.

@DavidScarlett to be clear i'm talking about the machines at planet fitness.  in addition to the beginning of the movement not being resisted by the weight stack, the first weight stack movement is only the top weight being moved.  Is this done on purpose by Planet Fitness, or is this a defect in the machine.

That sounds like poor manufacturing quality on the machines rather than intentional design. Do you have any other gyms available to you that you could switch to?

@DavidScarlett ok thanks.
